Typing in the Terminal on Ubuntu takes seconds until the typed character appears
The problem: typing in the terminal on Ubuntu takes seconds until the typed character appears.
I first noticed this after I moved large chunks of data onto another LUKS encrypted HDD which I mounted via /etc/fstab automatically.
Typing in the terminal (I'm using the default bash) responded uncannily slowly. First I thought that the problem is the additional HDD, but after I reinstalled Ubuntu on a new SSD, the problem kept coming back, but I did not mount the HDD at all. I don't think it's the hardware, as the other OS does not have any problem (dual boot on the Samsung 990 Pro).
Details:

Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, full disk encryption with LUKS on a Samsung 870 QVO 4TB Sata 6Gb/s
Also reproducible on a Samsung 990 Pro 4TB M.2 vMVE (2 TB partition without encryption)
4x8GB of RAM @2133 MT/s, at least 15GB free.
CPU: i7-6700K, all 8 cores < 10% usage

I already tried:

setting fs.inotify.max_user_watches to values between default 65536 and high value 1048576
rebooting multiple times
clearing the bash history
unmounting all devices
closing all programs which might slow down the FS (e.g. PhpStorm, GitKraken)

I already checked:

/var/log/dmesg
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/kern.log

I came across methods to debug slow processed and went with strace -T -f -s9999 -p6673, here's the output of me pressing arrow up twice:
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <1.867761>
read(0, "\33", 1)                       = 1 <0.000091>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.000008>
read(0, "[", 1)                         = 1 <0.000007>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.000007>
read(0, "A", 1)                         = 1 <0.000007>
write(2, "echo $$", 7)                  = 7 <0.000009>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.660089>
read(0, "\33", 1)                       = 1 <0.000024>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.000062>
read(0, "[", 1)                         = 1 <0.000040>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.000007>
read(0, "A", 1)                         = 1 <0.000007>
write(2, "\10\10\10\10\10\10\10cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches", 48) = 48 <0.000008>

What puzzles me is the first pselect6 call, which runs for over a second. That's definitely the culprit, but I don't know how to debug the problem from here.
Here's another strace where I'm typing only spaces:
strace: Process 6673 attached
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <2.216155>
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1 <0.000015>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000075>
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1 <0.000042>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <0.923598>
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1 <0.000017>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000011>
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1 <0.000012>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <1.504578>
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1 <0.000016>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000012>
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1 <0.000008>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <1.783754>
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1 <0.000016>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000013>
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1 <0.000009>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [0]) <1.664852>
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1 <0.000015>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000078>
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1 <0.000009>
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}strace: Process 6673 detached
 <detached ...>

Sometimes pselect6 is really slow with 2.2 seconds, sometimes it's fast.

Are you seeing https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509058/input-delay-on-terminal-ubuntu-22-04-4?

@muru thank you linking that question. It seems to be the same issue.It seems that stack exchange does not propose topics from other networks sites.

"It seems that stack exchange does not propose topics from other networks sites" – It's not necessarily a bad thing. We don't want our questions about cat to be linked to pets.stackexchange.com .

@KamilMaciorowski Nor do we want kill, abort, daemon, etc. to cross over. That would be bad. :)

@KamilMaciorowski no, it's probably not :D that was not meant as a negative criticism, just pointing out a fact.

As @muru pointed out, there's a duplicate on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509058/input-delay-on-terminal-ubuntu-22-04-4
My problem was not fixed but got a bit better by upgrading the packages xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-core xwayland via apt update && apt upgrade which were released Apr 10. I assume something related the the bug was fixed in those packages. But it did not solve the problem completely
I tested the answer which proposes to upgrade mutter to the development build: https://askubuntu.com/a/1509474/1341824
This one solved the problem and i also got rid of visual bugs, like flickering in PhpStorm
